Can we add additional layers on top of a quantized model to fine tune?
Is it possible to use a quantised model (e.g. int8) and add layers (e.g. PyTorch Linear) to do fine tuning in PyTorch?
If possible, how to convert the quantized model output vectors to feed to the added layers? Because I suppose the added layers would only work with the default fp32 data format.
